# ¿Como hago añado datos en un conjunto usando .split?

Tags: java, netbeans, eclipse, condiciones, split

Buenos Tardes tengo un problema con un ejercicio, y es ya hice toda la lógica, pero necesito añadir datos en un conjuntos usando un .split o espacio, ejm quiero añadir 3,4 pero los quiero añadir con un espacio (" ") ósea 3 4 igual aquí dejo el enunciado del problema https://programmersought.com/article/8456538698/ Si me ayudan estaría genial gracias

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class IWannaBeTheGuy {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int entrada = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    TreeSet<Integer> conjunto = new TreeSet<>();
       int p = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
       while(p-- >=1 ){
           conjunto.add(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().split(" ")));  //Como hago los " "  esta mal aqui
       }
        int q = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
       while(q-- >=1 ){
           conjunto.add(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));   //Como hago los " "
       }
    if (conjunto.size()== entrada) {
        System.out.println("I become the guy. ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Oh, my keyboard!");
      }
    }
 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El error se produce porque el código `int p = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());` Lee la línea `3 1 2 3` y luego intenta convertir la cadena en un entero y eso produce el error `NumberFormatException`.

Para obtener el valor de `p` se puede leer la cadena y usar `split()` para crear un arreglo:

```
String[] pStr = br.readLine().split(" ");
int p = Integer.parseInt(pStr[0]); // el valor de p es el primer elemento
```

Luego:

```
// agregar al conjunto los valores que están en el arreglo pStr
while(p-- >= 1 ){
   conjunto.add(Integer.parseInt(pStr[p]));
}
```

De igual forma para el valor de `q`.

Comment: GRAX BRO :V quedo bien

Comment: bro sera que me podrias revisar un ejercicio igual a este con un error muy relacionado porfavor  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395282/como-arreglo-este-problema-en-la-entrada-de-datos